# How to open an attachment using a link in an xpage?

Tags: file-upload, xpages

How to open an attachment in an xpage using a link url? What are all the fields iln the url? Pls explain. Also about the document folder created in the 'xsppers' folder.

Comment: Can this help? http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM

Comment: Also try the File Download control... no URL required.

Comment: how to use the file download control to display the attachment in the page?

Comment: can we set the document id? It's not the same for every attachment.

Comment: I'm brand new to xpages. so pls bear with my very basic questions. i need all your help.

Comment: where to use the file download control? i used it and associated it with a field in a form which holds the uploaded file. Also i tried creating a view and it too failed to display the file. so how to use the file download control?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer how to open a attached Image is:

```
http://pathToyourDatabase/DatabaseName.nsf/0/DocumentUniversalID/$File/MyImage.jpg
```

you can create this link with:

```
var imageurl = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath() + "/0/" +  
                /*in my case: viewEntry.getDocument().getUniversalID()*/ 
                + "/$File/"+ AttachmentName;
```

placing this link in the `src` attribute of an `<img>` or in the `url` attribute of the `<xp:image>` tag will dislay this image on your xPage. This example works fine for me but for other Attachments you maby have to add `?OpenElement` after the AttachmentName.

**Update:**
I did a short experiment on this with a pdf file and it worked without the `?OpenElement` just use the code to generate the url it should work. Additional you can look @ [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604326/convert-embedded-pictures-in-database).

Comment: As in the profiles, how to add a place for an image and let users upload image to display in that place? similar to profile picture setting.

Comment: Nota bene: doesn't work that way in an XPiNC app. You want to use http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM