# Override Content Disposition Type for Attachments Opened Through xPages URLs

Tags: xpages

Is there a way to override the content disposition header for an attachment opened through an xPage URL? I am attempting to open attachments/pdf's in the browser as opposed to the default which is to download/save.

This question was also asked on [Wissel's site](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM) by Mark Leusink, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Never found a solution to that using standard XPages file links. Only solution I know of is to generate the links as described here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729334/how-to-open-an-attachment-using-a-link-in-an-xpage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take:

- Use an [XAgent](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/shwl-7mgfbn) to read the attachment stream instead of linking to the attachment directly. There you can use the following to overwrite attachment/inline and file name.

```
response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "inline; Filename=invoice.pdf");
```

- Be nice to your admin and use a [web site rule](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc%2FH_WEB_SITE_RULES.html) to overwrite the HTTP header for your attachment urls. No code change in your application required and can be on a per application base

HTH
:-) stw

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try both of these approaches. Can see some advantages with each.

Comment: I am having trouble with both of these examples. Do you know of any examples I can crib? Maybe one on your site, which I lean on frequently.

Comment: for approach 1: update your question with the code you tried. The trick there is copying an inputstream (the attachment) to an outputstream (the XAgent response) - Apache Commons has ready classes for that. But I would go down the route of web site rule (a header rule is what you need). Which rule did you try?

Comment: I tried the HTTP response headers, then tried adding contentType, Cache-Control and content-disposition in the custom header. Not sure where to test that out to see if it works, but the change failed (after restarting http).

Comment: Did you check what actually got transmitted over the wire?

Comment: No, should probably do that. I should be able to use firebug for that right?