# XPages: File Download control link url

Tags: file, xpages, lotus-domino

I have a file download control that lists attachments from some documents in my database.
I want to display an icon next to each row and make it a link to the attachment of the row.

If not sure how to do it for each row, let's assume that i have only 1 row. How can i get the link of the attachment so as to declare it as href in a link control?

Comment: are you using the xp:download control? If yes that should display icons for pdf, image etc... if you enable Show Type. Or  if not maby this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729334/how-to-open-an-attachment-using-a-link-in-an-xpage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i already mentioned in my Comment if you are using a `<xp:fileDownload>` you can add a Icon if you set `displayType="true"` and because you didnt add code to your question i guess your code could look something like this:

```
//..your code
                <xp:panel id="row">
                    <xp:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoDocument
                            var="document1"
                            action="openDocument"
                            documentId="#{javascript://example... viewEntry.getDocument().getUniversalId()}">
                        </xp:dominoDocument>
                    </xp:this.data>
                    <xp:fileDownload
                        rows="30"
                        id="fileDownload1"
                        displayLastModified="false"
                        value="#{document1.Body}"
                        displayType="true">
                    </xp:fileDownload>
                </xp:panel>
//..your code
```

or if you dont use a `<xp:fileDownload>` and maby just Display rows with the attachment Name you could use something like this:

```
//... your code
            <xp:panel id="row">
            <xp:repeat
                id="repeat1"
                rows="30"
                value="#{javascript:@AttachmentNames()}"
                indexVar="attachmentIndex"
                var="attachment">
                <xp:link
                    escape="true"
                    text="#{javascript:attachment;}"
                    id="link1"
                    target="_blank">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                        var url = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath() + "/0/" +  
            /*in my case: viewEntry.getDocument().getUniversalID()*/ 
            + "/$File/"+ AttachmentName;        
                        return url;}]]></xp:this.value>
                    <xp:image id="image1">
                        <xp:this.url><![CDATA[#{javascript://
                            var pdfImage = 'pdf.gif';
                            if(attachment.indexOf("pdf")> 0)
                                return pdfImage;
                            }]]></xp:this.url>
                    </xp:image>&#160;
                </xp:link>
                <br></br>
            </xp:repeat>
        </xp:panel>//...your code
```

The `<xp:repeat>` inside your row will create a link for each attachment inside of your document you can remove it if you only have one attachment per document.